# Paginate With and Without Contain Key CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.x and would like to apply pagination in my controller but I would like it to be available in one case with a contain key and the other case without the contain key.  As an example consider this example:

```
class BlogController extends AppController {
    public $name = "Blog";
    public $paginate = array(
    'Post'=>array(
            'limit'=>30, 
            'conditions'=>array('publish'=>1),
            ),
        );

    function just_posts() {
        // I want to paginate Post as it is
    }

    function posts_with_comments() {
        // I want paginate Post with 'contain'=>'comments'
    }
}
```

In my real life case the purpose in doing this is for performance, to reduce the query time.  But I am at a loss how to implement this.  The $this->paginate(...) will only accept an argument to filter records.  Is there a way to make two paginators available for the same model in a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to modify your controller's `paginate` property within the relevant action to include the `contain` before doing the paginate:-

```
$this->paginate['Post']['contain'] = 'Comment';
```

This would extend the controller's defaults for the specific action.

Comment: Thanks @drmonkeyninja, this is very useful to know.  I had also hit the same problem when setting limit for paginate.  I am not sure if I am more happy or embarrassed :)